# ImportError raised in linux while running fine locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

When I run my code locally on my Windows machine, the code runs fine but when I deploy the code to the remote Linux server the ImportError is raised:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'client'
```

**Folder Structure:**

```
project
 |
 +-- main.py
 |
 +-- smpplib
      |
      +-- __init__.py
      |
      +-- client.py
      |
      +-- ...
      |
      +-- tests
           |
           +-- __init__.py
           |
           +-- ...
```

**The main.py:**

```
import smpplib
from smpplib import client, #and the rest of the submodules
```

- I packaged the whole project folder in **venv**, but I still get the same error in the remote server.
- remote server doesn't have any access to internet

**+ Edit:** When I run `import smpplib` on python REPL and then invoke `smpplib` on local machine I get :

```
`<module 'smpplib' from 'C:\\pathToProject\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\smpplib\\__init__.py'>`
```

But in the remote linux I get the following:

```
<module 'smpplib' (namespace)>
```

Comment: Are you sure the user running the python script in your server has read access to the folders where the packages are?

Comment: @nonDucor Yes, the user and also the group has read access to the folder and subfolders.